# Can i get the info about who deployed the bits on a cloudService?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-powershell

I need to know the last time a deployment was done against a cloud service. The cmdlet `Get-AzureDeployment` is helping with that.

Do we have a way by which I can also find the name/email of the guys who deployed the bits?

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, we can via Azure Portal to find the activity log.
Login the new portal->Monitor-Activity log:
[image]

[image]

More information about Azure Activity Log, please refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-activity-logs).

Comment: Agreed Jason , I can do this from the UI , but I have approximately 200+ cloud service and so I was looking for some  automation help/guidance here .

Comment: We can use the filter to check the status of the resource. Also we can create an email or webhook alert that triggers off an activity log event. another way, we can analyze it in PowerBI, or Stream it to an Event Hub for ingestion by a third-party service or custom analytics solution such as PowerBI, refer to the link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-activity-logs#what-you-can-do-with-the-activity-log

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.

Comment: @himanshu Should be able to achieve the same by polling activity logs from Azure REST API with predefined filters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/events

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Activity Log supports management plane records through Azure Resource Manager (ARM) only. If customer is deploying the cloud service via the older Azure Service Management (ASM), these records won't show up in Browse -> Monitor -> Activity Logs.

For ASM management plane records, customer will need to either use the Classic Portal or the ASM management plane API -

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/gg715315.aspx